# Fixing a corrupted USB

Tags: usb, usb-storage, format, filesystem-corruption

My USB seems to be corrupted, and I am looking to format the entire thing. I have no desire to recover any data on it, and all I want to do is use it as a USB again. On Windows, the USB mounts, crashes file explorer, and ejects itself. On Mac, it never mounts, and pops into disk utility then suddenly disappears. I can't run any recovery processes on it on either OS. What are my options?

```
INFO: 64GB ExFAT, USB 3.0
```

Comment: I wonder if the hardware has failed. If not, repartitioning and format it as you would s hard drive.

Comment: If you even managed to format it, would you trust it again? No; throw it away.

Comment: I think it's a hardware failure, but I can't remove the bad sectors either. How can I do that?